# Why isn't centripetal acceleration considered in this problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

> Fairgoers ride a Ferris wheel with a radius of 6.00 m. The wheel completes one 
>   revolution every 30.0 s. If a rider accidentally drops a stuffed animal at the top of the wheel, where does it land relative to the base of the ride? (Note: The bottom of the wheel is 1.75 m above the ground.)

Solution: Determine tangential velocity, which is velocity in the horizontal direction = 1.26 m/s

Determine time it takes for bear to fall using $\Delta Y=gt^2/2 = 1.67$ s. Use this information to find $\Delta X = 2.11$ m.

My question is, why isn't the vertical acceleration equal to $g+Ca$?

Comment: @Harsh I think you mean that the centripetal acceleration is present only *while* a particle is moving in a circular path. What you said is the opposite of that.

Answer (score 5):

According to the problem, the stuffed animal has been dropped. That means the only force on it is gravity, so its acceleration after being dropped is $g$. It doesn't "remember" being dropped from a Ferris wheel - it only knows its current position and velocity; nothing else.

Comment: In other words centripetal acceleration is not considered because there isn't any acting on the bear.

Answer (score 1):

You can't add centripetal force and gravity, because they aren't the same type of concept.

Gravity, or tension in a string, or friction between a tire and the road are real ***sources*** of force.  They are there because of some physical structure and/or interaction.

Centripetal force is a calculation of the force that is ***needed*** to achieve some required circular motion.  The calculation is the first step in determining whether the required motion will even take place.

For example:  You are driving a 1000 kg NASCAR Sprint Cup car, at 240 km/hr into an unbanked curve with a radius of 500 meters.  Being an accomplished multi-tasker, you do some unit conversions, punch a few numbers into the centripetal force formula and come up with$$F_c=\frac{1000\times \left (\frac{240000}{3600}\right)^2}{500}=8889\text{ Newtons}$$ But this doesn't ***create*** the force!  And you need one, badly, and right now!

Gravity acts straight down, and the reaction force of the road acts straight up;  neither of these are acting in the direction of the needed centripetal force.  Pushing the accelerator or brake won't help;  these create friction forces acting forward or backward, not inward.  You try turning the wheel slightly, to add a sideways friction force (tires on road) that may be  enough to give you what you want.  Unfortunately, the car in front of you has blown its engine and dumped all its oil on the track.  No friction;  no force to supply the needed centripetal force; no moving in a circle.

After moving in a straight line for a few seconds, you **do** find a force that will, one hopes, do the job:  the outside wall will press inward with enough reaction force
to make you travel in a slightly larger circle, and also add friction to slow you down, which also reduces the centripetal force needed.

In the case of the stuffed animal, while on the ride, the only accelerated motion is circular;  you could calculate the centripetal force needed to accomplish this.  Then you could check the various forces acting on the toy:  gravity, radial tension/thrust from the spokes of the Ferris wheel, and tangential force from the bending of the spokes.  You might then decide that the toy was too massive;  that the structure of the wheel could not supply the needed force.

Comment: *"Centripetal force is a calculation of the force that is **needed**"* Er...this distinction is certainly not maintained by all authors. Rather centripetal force is whatever force which causes the circular motion. Indeed students are sometimes asked to identify which force that is (and expected to identify the tension in the string in the case of a whiled yo-yo or the normal force from the rails as the roller-coaster goes around a loop-dee-loop).

Comment: @dmckee:  I think we agree;  your wording is clearer!  Specifically, your 2nd and 3 rd sentences. The studnets you refer to would not **add** the centripetal force and the tension...

Comment: Ah...I see. Yes.

Answer (score 0):

> "*My question is, why isn't the vertical acceleration equal to $g+Ca$?*"

I find a very nice [explanation](http://www.real-world-physics-problems.com/ferris-wheel-physics.html) on internet.
You are missing some important facts of the situation involved.
**Fact 1**: There are only two forces acting on stuffed animal throughout its ride these are :
(a) Normal force $N$ and
 (b) The gravity $mg$.
**Fact 2**: The total force acting on the animal is the resultant of $\vec N$ and $\vec{mg}$. Since the animal is revolving this resultant will be equal to the centripetal force required for the given rotational motion at tangential speed 1.26 m/s i.e $\vec N+\vec {mg}=\vec F_c$ where $\vec F_c$ is the required centripetal force.

---

[image 1 http://www.physcs.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/physics_ferris_wheel_2.png](http://www.physcs.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/physics_ferris_wheel_2.png) 
In position (1) the magnitude  of $F_c$ is $|mg-N_1|$ in downward direction and in position (2) $F_c$ is in upward direction having magnitude $|N_2-mg|$
[image: image 2]

---

> *Eventually the animal is dropped at position (1)*

After the very moment the animal is dropped the *Normal* force acting on it disappears.
i.e $N$ becomes $0$ leaving the resultant force $mg$ in magnitude So the vertical acceleration is $g$ not $g+Ca$.

Comment: If the only forces on the passenger are gravity and the normal force, why doesn't the seat slide out from under him as the seat goes from the 9 o'clock to 6 o'clock position.  They have seat belts on those things for a reason...

Comment: @User58220 $\vec N$ maintains aproprriate direction. You are right the seat belts provide that mandatory normal force when they goes from 9 to 6. If horizontal speed becomes large then even at the top position the seat belt would provide the remaining $\vec N$ centripetal force to sustain circular motion.

Comment: @User58220 [In mechanics, the normal force $F_n$  is the component, perpendicular to the surface (surface being a plane) of contact](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_force). The surface might be of seat belt or of seat.